# javascript constructors involving unknown amounts of arguments...

Tags: javascript, constructor, arguments

I was messing with some js on codecadamy and got a bit sidetracked trying to make something work.

In essence I was creating a few objects that are loaded into a controller object and set as properties of it with two functions that print the properties and compare a string to the name property of each object in the controller.

I noticed I can do it if I make the objects in the prototype style and specify a normal function to handle setting the properties like so:

```
var friends = {};

friends.setUp = function() {
  this.friends = [];
  for(var i in arguments) {
    arguments[i].setUp();
    this.friends.push(arguments[i]);
  }
};

friends.list = function() {
  for(var i in this.friends) {
    console.log(this.friends[i]);
  }
};

friends.search = function(name) {
  for(var i in this.friends) {
    if(this.friends[i].firstName === name) {
      return this.friends[i];
    }
  }
};

var bill = {};

bill.setUp = function() {
  this.firstName = "Bill";
  this.lastName = "Gates";
  this.number = "(206) 555-5555";
  this.address = ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052'];
};

var steve = {};

steve.setUp = function() {
  this.firstName = "Steve";
  this.lastName = "Jobs";
  this.number = "(206) 555-5555";
  this.address = ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014'];
};

var mike = {};

mike.setUp = function() {
  this.firstname = "Mike";
  this.lastname = "Ryd";
  this.number = "(800) 555-5555";
  this.address = ['redacted'];
};

friends.setUp(bill, steve, mike);
friends.list();
var result = friends.search("Steve");
console.log(result);
```

However if I do it with constructors It does not work, example:

```
function bill() {
  this.firstName = "Bill";
  this.lastName = "Gates";
  this.number = "(206) 555-5555";
  this.address = ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052'];
};

function steve() {
  this.firstName = "Steve";
  this.lastName = "Jobs";
  this.number = "(206) 555-5555";
  this.address = ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014'];
};

function mike() {
  this.firstname = "Mike";
  this.lastname = "Ryd";
  this.number = "(800) 555-5555";
  this.address = ['redacted'];
};

function friends() {
  this.friends = [];
  for(var i in arguments) {
    this.friends.push(arguments[i]);
  }
};

friends.list = function() {
  for(var i in this.friends) {
    console.log(this.friends[i]);
  }
};

friends.search = function(name) {
  for(var i in this.friends) {
    if(this.friends[i].firstName === name) {
      return this.friends[i];
    }
  }
};

var bill = new bill();
var steve = new steve();
var mike = new mike();
var friends = new friends(bill, steve, mike);
friends.list();
var result = friends.search("Steve");
console.log(result);
```

I was wondering if this is a limitation of using constructors or am I messing up the syntax somewhere? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with constructors with an unknown number of arguments, but rather you are not assigning methods on your objects appropriately.  They need to be put on the prototype so that they will be inherited by all objects that are created by this particular constructor.  So in your code, these:

```
friends.list = function() {...}
friends.search = function() {...}
```

needs to be changed to:

```
friends.prototype.list = function() {...}
friends.prototype.search = function() {...}
```

Like this:

```
friends.prototype.list = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.friends.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.friends[i]);
  }
};

friends.prototype.search = function(name) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.friends.length; i++) {
    if(this.friends[i].firstName === name) {
      return this.friends[i];
    }
  }
};
```

Then, this code should work fine:

```
var bill = new bill();
var steve = new steve();
var mike = new mike();
var friends = new friends(bill, steve, mike);
friends.list();
var result = friends.search("Steve");
console.log(result);
```

And, then the code works as you would expect here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ba4me8ua/

---

FYI, you'll noticed that I changed the way you iterate through the `arguments` object items to be more array-like and avoid any chance of getting any non-numeric properties in the iteration.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it. Makes sense because the functions are properties as well so if the constructor only exists as a constructor before the object it initialized those functions have nothing to attach to until its created. Would one way of doing this be preferred over the other? I find just making "setUp" functions and setting my properties as needed works better then making constructors.

Comment: Variable arguments on a constructor are fine.  It does complicate inheritance a bit if the derived objects want to have their own arguments too (but even in that case, it can be managed).  But, I can't really say that a `.setup()` (or usually called `.init()`) method is a better or worse idea than arguments to the constructor. You can do it either way.

Comment: But, your first block of code does not allow you to make multiple `friends` objects.  That is only allows the one statically declared singleton object.  Your second block of code is more flexible.